# what is the interval within which C has a probability of at least 0.75 of lying?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

During an 8-hour shift, the proportion of time X that a sheet-metal stamping machine is down for
maintenance or repairs has a beta distribution with α = 1 and β = 2 ; that is,
f (x) =2(1 − x), for 0 < x < 1, 0, elsewhere.
The cost (in $100s) of this downtime in lost production and repair expenses is given by
C = 10 + 20X + 4X^2.

I was wondering if c will have a beta distribution too.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, $C$ does not have beta distribution. Moreover: there exist a lot of intervals satisfying the above condition: any interval within wich $X$ has a probability at least $0.75$ provides an interval for $C$ with the same probability.

One can suppose that the interval should be from zero to some $t$. And then you need to find $t$ such that 
$$
\mathbb P(0\leq C\leq t)=0.75.
$$
Note that $C=10+20X+4X^2$ is the quadratic function of $X$ with the $x$-coordinate of the vertex $x=-20/8=-2.5$. The vertex is outside the domain of $X$ and parabola opens upwards. Therefore $C$ strictly increases when $X$ increases for all $X$ inside $[0,\,1]$. It means that the inequality $0\leq C\leq t$ is equivalent to inequality $0\leq X\leq s$, where $s$ can be found by integration of given probability density function over interval $[0,s]$:
$$0.75=\mathbb P(X\leq s)=\int_0^s 2(1-x)dx.$$
If you find $s$ then you get the right endpoint $t$ of interval for $C$ from monotonicity of quadratic function on $[0,\, 1]$:
$$0.75=\mathbb P(X\leq s)=\mathbb P(10+20X+4X^2<10+20s+4s^2).$$
Then $t=10+20s+4s^2$.